# Using Openfiler inside a virtualmachine and VmWare Fault Tolerance

Tags: vmware-esx, iscsi, openfiler, fault-tolerance

currently I have 2 servers with Fault Tolerance working with another server with openfiler as a iSCSI server (looks like without that Fault Tolerance does not work). I would like to remove that server and put the openfiler distribution as another Fault Tolerance protected machine. Is this possible? This way i could save one server and also have faster HD access.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst openfiler will work inside a VM perfectly well, and work as an FT VM I think you've got a bit of a dependancy loop there - where is the .vmdk for the FT Openfiler VM going to live? if it's FT it needs to be somewhere central - meaning another Openfiler or similar, thus negating the benefit right?

Let me know if I've misunderstood the situation.

Comment: I'm really not sure why the files need to be central. Aren't they duplicated as the whole virtual machine with FT?

Comment: no, no they're not, they're specifically held centrally so that all that's transmitted over the network is the memory/CPU/IO/registers - otherwise it would flood even a 10Gbps link.

Comment: Oh crap :( Then i would not be able to implement that solution ... well, thanks for you help mate.